# When i run npm start then it show me this type of error,What is solution for this problem?

Tags: npm

[image]

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/projects/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/projects/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/macbookpro/.npm/_logs/2022-05-08T14_59_17_963Z-debug.log
macbookpro@MacBooks-MacBook-Pro projects %
```

Answer (score 1):

Any npm command related to your project should be run from the root of your project (where package.json resides). You probably forgot to cd into your project directory after you created/initialized (npm init) your project.